# When used my svelte component twice in angular consumer, Same data is getting printed twice even after passing different configs because of store

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-store

Here is the glipmse of my angular consumer and ' document-listing-web-component ' is the tag name of my svelte component.

```
   <document-listing-web-component 
        [attr.configuration]='listConfiguration' 
        [attr.myfavorites]="myFavorites"
        [attr.documentdetailsenable]="documentdetailsenable"
        [attr.partnumbersearchEnable]="partNumberSearchEnable">
    </document-listing-web-component>
    <document-listing-web-component 
        [attr.configuration]='gridConfiguration' 
        [attr.myfavorites]="myFavorites"
        [attr.documentdetailsenable]="documentdetailsenable"
        [attr.partnumbersearchEnable]="partNumberSearchEnable">
    </document-listing-web-component>
```

Now the problem is even am initializing the component twice with configration the same store variables are updated with the latest congfiguration values and applying changes to one component is effecting the other too.....can anyone help me if you have faced similar issue using svelte .

I tried Creating custom component, but its not allowing to create a it for the second time on the same component.

We are planning a rework on this eliminating the svelte store and using the services, any other helpful things will be appriciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.